# LineBackgroundSpan: PARAGRAPH span must start at paragraph boundary Error

Tags: android, html, android-layout, textview

I am trying to apply rounded corners to my code tags in a given string

My string looks like this :

```
This is a test <br/><br/> <code> Some code block here </code>
```

I want to apply the [CustomLineBackgroundSpan](https://medium.com/@Semper_Viventem/simple-implementation-of-rounded-background-for-text-in-android-60a7706c0419) (for rounded corners) to only the text between the `code` tags using a `TagHandler`

```
class TagHandler() : Html.TagHandler {
    override fun handleTag(opening: Boolean, tag: String, output: Editable, xmlReader: XMLReader) {
        when (tag) {
            CODE_TAG -> handleCodeTag(opening, output)
        }
    }
   

    private fun handleCodeTag(opening: Boolean, output: Editable) = when {
        opening -> {
            start(output, CodeItem())
        }
        else -> {
             // just applies the span based on start and end index of the marker
             end<CodeItem>(
                output,
                // basic sample
                LineBackgroundSpan.Standard(Color.LTGRAY)
            )
        }
    }
```

But the above setup doesnt seem to work for all kinds of strings.

Some strings ex: `This is a test <br/><br/> <code> Some code block here </code> some more text` fail with
`PARAGRAPH span must start at paragraph boundary (5 follows  )`

How can I resolve this ?